# Rails model has_many order desc group by only containing model

Tags: group-by, ruby-on-rails-5, sql-order-by

`post.similarities.order("similarity DESC").group_by(:afterscholar_id).first(4).each_with_index`

My post has similarities, and I need to be searching exclusively through the ones that contain anything more than 'nil' in the variable afterscholar_id

Comment: What do you mean with _I need to be looking only at the ones that contain an entry in the variable afterscholar_id_?

Comment: Is `post.similarities.where.not(afterscholar_id: nil)` what you're looking for?